# Make so that div changes color for a brief time when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animations, css-transitions

I've got a setup where I'm using divs as buttons, and when they're clicked they add to ingredients to my burger.

JS:

```
<div id="ingredientBox">
        <Ingredient
        ref="ingredient"
        v-for="item in currentIngredients"
        v-on:increment="addToBurger(item)"
        :item="item"
        :lang="lang"
        :ui-labels="uiLabels"
        :key="item.ingredient_id">
      </Ingredient>
    </div>
```

With CSS:

```
.ingredient {
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f28a;
  padding: 0.8em;
  width: 23vh;
  height: 19vh;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I now want the div to react visually when clicked (maybe change color for like 0.2 seconds or something. I've looked around and only find info on how to change color permanently, is there a simple way of changing the color for just a brief moment?

Comment: Sounds like you are after the [CSS `:active` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```css
#ingredientBox:active {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS keyframe animation to pull this off:

```
@keyframes animate-burger-button {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
  }
}

#ingredientBox:active {
  animation: animate-burger-button 0.8s forwards;
}
```

I would also add another note to try and use a button instead of a div, make accessibility a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout` to add a class to the button and then remove it.

**code:**

```js
buttonTrigger() {
   element.classList.add('somesyle'); // add colour changing class to element

   setTimeout(() => {
       element.classList.remove('somestyle'); //remove the class after 0.2 seconds
   }, 200)

}
```

**EDIT**

I was going to also suggest using CSS `keyframes` but @AlexanderKaran already suggested it. That is a good option too.